# C# Voice Recognition parse values that user says

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I want to make a program to basically check airport weather from a website.
i want my code to listen for a command (witch is to check weather) and then the user will tell the program where to check the weather by ICAO (4 letter code for aiports eg. EHAM = Amsterdam Schiphol) 
im stuck on how to make the recognitionEngine to listen to what the user has said, convert it from the phonetic alphabet to normal letters and combine the 4 letters to input it into the url to get the weather information. once i have the 4 letters i know how to implement it into the URL.

What i have sofar: `

```
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace Voice_Reco_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine RecEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Choices commands = new Choices();
        commands.Add(new string[] { "check metar for ","alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot", "golf", "hotel", "india", "juliet", "kilo", "lima", "mike", "november", "oscar", "papa", "quebec", "romeo", "sierra", "tango", "uniform", "victor", "whiskey", "x-ray", "yankee", "zulu" });

        GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        gBuilder.Append(commands);

        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

        RecEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);

        RecEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        RecEngine.SpeechRecognized += RecEngine_SpeechRecognized;


    }

    private void RecEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
       switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
```

// here the user says the 4 phonetic letters and those the program needs to copy and insert into URL 
                case "check metar for"  :

```
                break;

        }
    }

    private void BtnEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RecEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        BtnDisable.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void BtnDisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RecEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
        BtnDisable.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

}
`

EDIT: Edited the code and removed 4 different choices

Comment: Create a global variable and parse the contents?

Comment: Sorry but im not sure i understand how that would work.... there are thousands of airports in the world with unique ICAO codes ... having a command for each would probably slow down the program. that's why i want my program to basically copy what user has said.

Comment: i have removed the choices as that wouldn't work ... but now i dont know how to listen and eventually convert phonetic alphabet into normal alphabet

Comment: You just create a HashTable where for every word like "alpha" you put letter like "a". Then you use that table to convert words one by one.

Comment: would the letter be stored somewhere as a string or directly inputted to the URL? i would like it to be a string that i can call up in the code. is that possible? haven't worked with HashTables yet. and how would i integrate that into the speech recognition?

Comment: I have created a Hashtable with all the letters but now i dont know how to intergrate that into the voice recognition... as the voice recognition output is in `e.result.Text ` i just dont know how to do it when the command is said "check metar for": as then it needs to listen to the 4 phonetic letters as Alpha etc and input them into a string